# Date-picker of Bootstrap 3 is cleaning another components, what could be?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

For my date inputs, I'm using `datepicker` from bootstrap in javascript. But, when I'm done from select a date or just lost the focus of the selector, another components from the form is reseting its data.

**Javascript:**

```
Tc.MaskDate = (function(){
    
    function MaskDate() {
        this.inputDate = $('.js-date');
    }
    
    MaskDate.prototype.enable = function() {
        this.inputDate.mask('00/00/0000');
        this.inputDate.datepicker({
            orientation: 'bottom',
            language: 'pt-BR',
            autoclose: true
        });
    }
    
    return MaskDate;
    
})();
```

**HTML:**

```
class="js-date"
```

**What happens:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
$('.js-date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    }).on('hide', function(event) {
    evnt.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that those dates are for a search on those "members" displayed in the grid? I believe that as you `focus` the `datepicker` control and leave `focus` it is adding a default value to that `input` model like `1/1/1967` but not actually displaying it - therefore re-rendering the grid with no results found.

Maybe this will lead you in the right direction, sorry if it's off-base.

Comment: nice shot, but is just the creation of projects with users! and I still looking for a solution.